# How do I get the current active application of the window manager over ssh without -X

Tags: ubuntu, x11, gnome, wayland

I want to get the currently active window in whatever window manager is in use. So, I would like this work with gnome or kde. But I'm happy if the solution only works with gnome to start. This is a newer installation of Ubuntu so I'm assuming it is Wayland?

I need this to work over ssh. I want to track the time of running applications in the foreground.

I tried using `xdotool getactivewindow`. However even if I login using the same user account as the window manager is running against, and set the display and xauthority variables, it still doesn't work. Other threads indicate I need to set the -X switch but I'm using an ssh client on Android and don't have client side X11 so that's not workable.

I tried using the gdbus command but it didn't work either

```
$ gdbus call   --session   --dest org.gnome.Shell   --object-path /org/gnome/Shell   --method org.gnome.Shell.Eval "
    global
      .get_window_actors()
      .map(a=>a.meta_window)
      .find(w=>w.has_focus())
      .get_wm_class()"   | cut -d'"' -f 2
(false, '')
```

Is there any hacky way to do this? I just need the name for accounting purposes not any details beyond that.